# I can't move blocks

Tags: 7, blocks

I currently have a site that has quite a lot of blocks (about 120 in 1 region and many others in other regions).

Recently the Block admin page stopped working for me. I can't add any blocks through that screen, however when I go to the block detail page, I can.

All new blocks are handed the weight 0, and I cant change that (not by drag and drop, neither by manually entering the weight).

Anyone who know how I can fix this? Is it because there are too many blocks?

Comment: What does JavaScript console say about it? Use Google Chrome, Firebug plugin in Firefox, or similar tool in a browser you are using. Just not IE, please.

Comment: The javascript console is clean, no errors or warnings.

Answer (score 1):

120 blocks in one regions seems to be excessive, you may want to attempt to consolidate them into a custom block and use [context](https://drupal.org/project/context) to set those.  Also may want to look at creating multiple regions that reside in the same area

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, where I couldn't change the weight of my blocks and all new blocks had a weight of 0. I deleted a bunch of old blocks (about 50) and I was then able to assign weight to them again. I assume the issue was I had too many.

Comment: Yes it looks like this. My plan is to delete the old ones and create some extra regions. It seems like the limit is only per region. Thanks for your answer!